# Why is .NET adding SP Params twice?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I've got a winforms app and I'm calling an SP when I insert a row.
I'm defining the params, but it's adding extra params on the end.

```
da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.GridInsert", new SqlConnection(MC.ConnectionString));
da.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ApplyTo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = applyTo;
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ApplyType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = applyType;
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ApplyValue", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = applyValue;
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.BigInt, 0, "ID");
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@InstanceID", SqlDbType.BigInt, 0, "InstanceID");
```

Above, the 1st 3 params get their values from variables.
The next 2 are tied to grid cols.
However, this is what's sent to the DB.

```
exec dbo.GridInsert @ApplyTo='xxx',@ApplyType='xxx',@ApplyValue='xxx',@ID=NULL,@InstanceID=38,@ApplyTo='xxx',@ApplyType='xxx',@ApplyValue='xxx'
```

Notice that the 1st 3 params are put on the front and the end.
Also, if I don't add those 3 params to the collection, they're put on the end anyway.
Anybody have any clues?

Comment: Are there extra parameters the stored procedure requires? Also, it's recommended to use `.AddWithValue` instead of `.Add`, as it's been deprecated.

Comment: @eltoro , you have it switched. [Can We Stop using AddWithValue() Already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @eltoro The overload of `Add` that just takes a parameter name and value is deprecated. The overloads that specify the data type are still very much active.

Comment: @eltoro - Only `Add(string, object)` has been deprecated.  The overload of `Add` used here is fine, and prevents accidentally inferring the wrong type with `AddWithValue`.

Comment: @SeanMcCown - are you *sure* the add calls only happen once like shown here? Also, how are you observing what is sent to the database?  Does it have any effect?

Comment: Oh my bad guys, sorry for the incorrect info.